# Codeigniter PHP: Error when load config database in controller?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, oracle11g

I have got error "Your application/config/database.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array." when load config database in codeigniter:

Here my controller:

```
$this->config->load('database');
```

Here my file database.php:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$tnsname = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))';
$db['default']['hostname'] = $tnsname;
$db['default']['username'] = 'system';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxxxxx';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I load config file database and I want to change config database from controller? will know how to do that?

Comment: This may help you http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

Please specify the database name in the database.php(for `$db['default']['database']`) and also in your controller mention `$this->config->load('database_name')` that you have set in the configuration file